# How to add an image to the hyperlink in html?

Tags: html, css

I have tried the following code

```
<a href="http://www.tutorials.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="cart.jpg"       />Visit this for tutorials</a>
```

When I executed this I was getting an image first and then the link but I am not getting that image included in the link.

I want the answer using both HTML tags and CSS.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3BJc6/1

Comment: maybe there is no file "cart.jpg" in your directory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the HTML code `<a href="website URL"><img src="picture URL" /></a>` Insert the image link in "Picture URL" and the link you want to take the viewer to in "website URL".

Comment: That code is in the question already